# Use Sed to replace numbers in URL within Splunk

Tags: regex, sed, splunk, splunk-query

How can I extract alpha-numeric values within a URL? I have the following query that isn't replacing the right values.

Example Input Data:

```
/example/endpoint/here/34456dwf45
/endpoint/fddk449372
/434236/example/endpoint
```

Expected Output:

```
/example/endpoint/here/my_var
/endpoint/my_var
/my_var/example/endpoint
```

Current Query:

```
* | rex mode=sed field=request_url "s/(.*\\/)[^\/]+(\/.*)/\1my_var\2/" 
  | stats values(request_url)
```

How can I use sed to replace any alpha-numeric values within two / characters to be a string inside a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following `sed` command:

```
"s,(^|/)[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*($|/),\1my_var\2,"
```

Or, to replace overlapping matches and all occurrences use `(?![^/])` instead of `($|/)` and add `g` flag at the end:

```
"s,(^|/)[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*(?![^/]),\1my_var,g"
```

See the [first regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jsUW1s/1) and the [second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jsUW1s/2).

`s`  here means we need to replace strings. The delimiters are `,` (commas) as this way we do not have to escape forward slashes.

The `(^|/)[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*($|/)` pattern matches

- `(^|/)` - Group 1 (`\1`): start of aline or `/`
- `[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*` - 0+ letters, a digit and then 0 or more digits or letters
- `($|/)` - Group 2 (`\2`): end of a line or `/`
- `(?![^/])` - is a negative lookahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with any char but `/`.

Comment: For some reason, the results only replace the first occurrence of an alpha-numeric string (i.e. `/abc/v1/def/589639/abc` equates to `/abc/my_var/def/589639/abc` within my search results. Is there something Splunk does to retrieve different results than regular regex?

Comment: @Baily Try two things: 1) replace `($|/)` with `(?![^/])` and also remove `\2` from the replacement pattern and 2) add `g` after the last `,`. `"s,(^|/)[[:alpha:]]*[[:digit:]][[:alnum:]]*(?![^/]),\1my_var,g"`